# Could not establish connection to "hostname": Permission denied(publickey)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys

I cannot connect my remote server to Visual Studio Code, this is output on terminal and it gives me popup "Could not establish connection to "hostname": Permission denied(publickey)." Can someone help me?

`````
[15:10:39.411] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+138.68.106.1", attempt 1
[15:10:39.412] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[15:10:39.412] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:10:39.412] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[15:10:39.412] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[15:10:39.413] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\Nikola Nikitovic\.ssh\config
[15:10:39.413] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[15:10:39.413] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[15:10:39.413] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[15:10:39.413] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[15:10:39.413] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:10:39.414] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[15:10:39.414] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[15:10:39.414] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[15:10:39.414] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[15:10:39.414] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[15:10:39.414] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[15:10:39.424] VS Code version: 1.78.2
[15:10:39.424] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.102.0
[15:10:39.424] win32 x64
[15:10:39.426] SSH Resolver called for host: 138.68.106.1
[15:10:39.426] Setting up SSH remote "138.68.106.1"
[15:10:39.430] Using commit id "b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435" and quality "stable" for server
[15:10:39.435] Install and start server if needed````


I cannot connect my remote server to Visual Studio Code
`````

Comment: "Permission denied(publickey)" means the server accepts key-based authentication and you're failing to authenticate. Did you set up a key to access this server? Please [edit] your question to describe what you did to set up this key. It would also be helpful to try connecting using the `ssh` command-line utility, using the "-v" parameter to print debugging information, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output.